# Camel RabbitMq transactional consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to create a camel route having rabbitmq consumer inside a transaction.  I am using Spring boot and atomikos for tx management.  Rabbit MQ queue already has x-dead-letter-exchange and routing key set up.

How should I wrap my rabbitmq connection factory inside JTA tx manager ? I tried transact block but it didn't work. Also I don't see an option in RabbitMq component to set tx manager.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your rabbitMq connection factory inside of a Jms Component from camel.  When using WebSphereMQ I typically have a wrapping pattern of: JmsComponent -> Spring CachingConnectionFactory -> MQQueueConnectionFactory.  You can configure your transaction information on the JmsComponent.

Comment: well camel-rabbitmq component is build separately and can not be wrapped inside jms component. Though camel-amqp supports that but unfortunately it supports amqp 1.0 protocol and its not working with rabbitmq even after enabling amqp 1.0 plugin. I have raised this question on rabbitmq forum.

Comment: Don't use the camel-rabbitmq component directly.  You can easily leverage the camel-jms component and then plugin the rabbitMQ connection factory